# readdir: how do I know if it is a file or directory

Tags: android, c, ios

[readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) returns info about all item within the directory. How can I tell if the item is file or directory?

Thank you.

EDIT. Sorry, forgot to mention, that my time target platform is iOS and android.

Comment: I'm not sure that `readdir` is usable within an iOS application.  In any case, on that platform you'll be better served by using NSFileManager and the `-fileType` helper method, which can identify directories.

Comment: After looking into it, it appears `readdir` is usable on iOS, but there are some bugs with its implementation on iOS 4.x: https://devforums.apple.com/message/251591 .  I'd still recommend using the higher-level abstraction of NSFileManager for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for `d_type` being `D_DIR`.

Comment: @pic11, see my comment to Basile's answer.

Comment: Using `d_type` is likely to be about 50-1000 times faster than calling `stat` for every entry, but you should probably include fallback code for systems where `d_type` does not exist or in case it's not filled in.

Comment: @R.., yes, that's a good idea. But it all depends on OP's intentions. It might also be that the OP wants to examine the link target, I have no idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

dirent contains a member d_type which can evaluate to 0x8 if it is a file, so:

```
struct dirent *DirEntry;
...
if ( DirEntry->d_type == 0x8)
      //is a file
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, on the standard "POSIX" readdir operation you do not have the field d_type

> According to POSIX, the dirent structure contains a field char d_name[] of unspecified size, > with  at  most  NAME_MAX  characters  preceding  the  terminating  null  byte.
>         POSIX.1-2001 also documents the field ino_t d_ino as an XSI extension.  Use of other > fields will harm the portability of your programs.

The "standard way" is to do a lstat call on you file/dir and check the st_mode field of the struct stat, if your st_mode match S_ISDIR, you have a dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute a path for each entry in the directory (but perhaps you can skip `.` & `..` entries) and use the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call on that path.

This is useful if you want more information (e.g. modification time, size, ...) on the path.

Comment: It might also be useful in case of the system that doesn't support `d_type`, though since the question is tagged `linux`, it is very unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: There's no need to compute the path.  (At least, not on Linux > 2.6.16)  Since readdir is being used, there is already an open dirent so you can use fstatat with the relative path given in d_name.  (Use dirfd() to get the fd).